# Regex Javascript - Remove text between two html comments

Tags: javascript, html, regex, gruntjs

Well I have two html comments like this:

```
<!--Delete-->
Blah blah
blah blah
<!--Delete-->
```

And I want to remove it (including the comments, any character and newlines). Btw I am using javascript and Grunt to make the replacement.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**

Use the following JavaScript Regular Expression to match multiple instances of your custom `.html` comments and the content inside them:

```js
/\<\!\-\-Delete\-\-\>((.|[\n|\r|\r\n])*?)\<\!\-\-Delete\-\-\>[\n|\r|\r\n]?(\s+)?/g
```

---

Then register a custom [Function Task](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask) inside your `Gruntfile.js` as shown in the following gist:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        // ... Any other Tasks
    });

    grunt.registerTask('processHtmlComments',
        'Remove content from inside the custom delete comments',
        function() {
            var srcDocPath = './src/index.html', // <-- Define src path to .html
                outputDocPath = './dist/index.html',// <-- Define dest path for .html

                doc = grunt.file.read(srcDocPath, {encoding: 'utf8'}),
                re = /\<\!\-\-Delete\-\-\>((.|[\n|\r|\r\n])*?)\<\!\-\-Delete\-\-\>[\n|\r|\r\n]?(\s+)?/g,
                contents = doc.replace(re, '');

            grunt.file.write(outputDocPath, contents, {encoding: 'utf8'});
            console.log('Created file: ' + outputDocPath);
        });

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'processHtmlComments'
    ]);

};
```

**Additional notes**

Currently running `$ grunt` via the CLI does the following:

1. Reads a file named `index.html` from the `src` folder.
2. Deletes any content from inside the starting and closing custom comments, *`<!--Delete-->`*, including the comments themselves.
3. Writes a new `index.html`, excluding the unwanted content, to the `dist` folder.

Both the values for `srcDocPath` and `outputDocPath` will probably need to be redefined as per your projects requirements.

---

**EDIT** Updated Regex to also allow inline comment usage. For example:

```html
<p>This text remains <!--Delete-->I get deleted<!--Delete-->blah blah</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the below regex, 
we check with a word starts with

`\<\!` => after escape => `<!`
Then `(.)*` for anything
then skip first tag end `\-\>`
Then anythig `(.)*`
Then at end of comment `\-\-\>`
and check for a global match `g`;

```js
var text="<div>hello there</div><!--Delete-->Blah blahblah blah<!--Delete--><span>Hello world</span>";
var re=/\<\!(.)*\-\>(.)*\-\-\>/g;
console.log(text.replace(re,""));
```

But generally HTML comments look like

```
<!--comments blah blah blah //-->
```

for that , here is another regex

```js
var text = "<span>Hi there</span><div>Hello world</div><!--comments blah blah blah //--><span>something</span>";
var re=/\<\!\-(.)*\/\/\-\-\>/g;
console.log(text.replace(re,""));
```